# Unable to render react-bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-bootstrap-table

I am trying to render some sample data using react bootstrap tables but somehow i am always getting the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

I had referred multiple questions on SO and several links but i'm unable to figure out the actual problem with the code. It is a very simple react program to display 2 rows in react-bootstrap table:

```
import React from 'react';

import BootstrapTable from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';
import TableHeaderColumn from 'react-bootstrap-table-next';

import 'react-bootstrap-table-next/dist/react-bootstrap-table2.min.css';

class Dependency extends React.Component
{

    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = 
        {
            products :
            [{
                id: 1,
                name: "Product1",
                price: 120
            }, 
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "Product2",
                price: 80
            }]
        }
    }

    render()
    {

        return(
            <BootstrapTable data={this.state.products}>
                <TableHeaderColumn isKey={true} dataField='id'>Product ID</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField='name'>Product Name</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField='price'>Product Price</TableHeaderColumn>
            </BootstrapTable>
        );
    }
}

export default Dependency;
```

Also i want to fix my column width of table as if my column data is long a single column takes space for the whole page.

Comment: I am also not sure why this error is popping up every time. I haven't use any filter function. The above is the all code.

Comment: I presume, BootstrapTable has filter function in it and it's trying to filter your products. Are you sure you added all data necessary to it ? Maybe there is some attribute you forgot

Comment: I think this will solve your problems, they removed `TableHeaderColumn`:

https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/migration.html

Comment: Yeah I checked the docs...
They have removed TableHeaderColumn,
After removing it my code is working fine...
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

those are bootstrap table component docs https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/table/

I'm not sure where you're importing the table from, since the table import is:

```
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table'
```

I suggest you follow the install of react bootstrap via the docs and use the docs for infos, since they're easy to follow:
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/

Here is an example of react bootstrap table:

```
import { Component, PureComponent } from "react";
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';

const debugDocuments = [{
    id: '1',
    name: 'doc 1',
    hash: 'f2baa1d88c9bcf2e1724b7a75b44eb7a',
    date: '07/15/2020 15:58:09',
    state: 'Started',
},
{
    id: '2',
    name: 'doc 2',
    hash: 'f2baa1d88c9bcf2e1724b7a75b44eb7a',
    date: '07/15/2020 15:58:09',
    state: 'Progress',
},
{
    id: '3',
    name: 'doc 3',
    hash: 'f2baa1d88c9bcf2e1724b7a75b44eb7a',
    date: '07/15/2020 15:58:09',
    state: 'Completed',
}]

class TableRow extends PureComponent {

    render() {
        const { 
            index, id, name, hash, date,
            state, 
        } = this.props;
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>{index}</td>
                <td>{name}</td>
                <td>{hash}</td>
                <td>{date}</td>
                <td>{state}</td>
            </tr>
        )
    }
}

class MainClass extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            documents: debugDocuments,
        };
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <Table responsive borderless striped hover>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>NOME</th>
                    <th>HASH</th>
                    <th>DATA</th>
                    <th>STATO</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {documents.map((item, index) => (
                    <TableRow key={item.id} index={index} name={item.name} id={item.id} hash={item.hash} date={item.date} state={item.state} />
                ))}
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: These are not the same libraries.